# Script works in IDLE, but .py-file doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-explorer, python-idle

I have a tkinter script, which runs just fine in IDLE. However, when I double click the .py-file from Windows Explorer, the console window flashes half a second and then it exits.

I was able to screenprint the console window. It says:

```
...etc.etc...
NameError: global name 'simpledialog' is not defined
```

`simpledialog` is a module in `tkinter` which I use in my script. As I do `from tkinter import *`, there is no need to explicitly write `tkinter.simpledialog`.

It works in IDLE, why not as .py?

Comment: if you have multiple versions of python you may be useing different versions for IDLE and .py, happened to me once, but speculation for what you are encountering.

Comment: Mine is **just a guess**, as I have no direct experience on windows machines (well, at least not after win98) but it might be that the path your python interpreter uses is set automatically when you use IDLE, while it is not when you double click a script.

Comment: Did you try starting the script with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`? Not sure if this fixes the issue, but worth a try nonetheless.

Comment: Serdalis: I've got only one version of Python, so that can't be the trouble.
@mac I can't say I fully understand what you're saying, but I noticed that another script - containing a Button, which is a tkinter module - does work from Windows Explorer! "Path-problems" seem to me (?) a bit too general to only affect tkinter.simpledialog.

Comment: @hochl I tried pythonw.exe (by renaming to .pyw). Now I don't see anything happen at all. Guess it's the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you start a command promt (start type cmd + enter) and then type `python script_file_name.py`

Comment: @Joram Same thing. Exactly the same NameError.

Answer (score 6):

IDLE uses Tkinter as its graphical environment. It is possible that your code is relying on a side effect of an import by IDLE itself. This is especially true if you use IDLE without a subprocess.

The `simpledialog` module does not import when using `from tkinter import *`.
Try adding this to your code:

```
import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your PATH environment variable so that your Python executable is found? You can find more information on how to do here - [Using Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html)

But you basically need to make sure that the folder containing python.exe (e.g. C:\Python32) is displayed when you type the following command from a prompt:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Comment: I updated the PATH environment variable just now, however the exact same NameError is still shown.

Comment: How do you use the simpledialog module in your code? Are you trying to use the SimpleDialog class from the simpledialog module?

Comment: I don't think so, I use it like this:
tempName=simpledialog.askstring("Name","Enter your name please.")

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with one of my scripts utilizing Tkinter.
Adding call to mainloop() fixed the issue.
See this tutorial for an example: [http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/#import[1](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/#import)

In my case, in the **init** function I have

```
def __init__(self,Width=400, Height=400):
        # Create GUI window ------------------------------            
        win = Tk()
        ...
```

in the end of **init** I added:

```
        win.mainloop()
```

Now it works by just running the file.
Hope this helps

Comment: While the advice to call mainloop is useful, it isn't related to this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar trouble for me just now, in my first week with python. But I dimly remembered a similar problem with a simple early test script and thought the trouble then was # comments.
So I tried that with my Tkinter infused .py script. It ran fine in IDLE as you say, then only flashed when clicked in windows. But there were a couple # commented lines at the top of file.

I took them all out and it now runs no sweat directly in windows. Have a look .. for #.

Sorry, can't seem to delete this post. Now the files work #comments included. Don't know what's up with that. ..

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the executable py file to a `file.pyw` fixed the problem. This tells python to execute it using the pythonw.exe which runs the script without the terminal/console in the background.

Not sure why this works, perhaps some screwed up environment variables from a previous python installation.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file's extension to pyw instead of py might solve the problem

Comment: If it did solve it what would the mechanism be? Explain the difference between .py and .pyw file extensions.