# Python's Tkinter simpledialog.askstring not working from command prompt

Tags: python, tkinter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Script works in IDLE, but .py-file doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319022/script-works-in-idle-but-py-file-doesnt-work)

So i wrote a gui in python's tkinter using python 3.2.2's IDLE. When i run the program from the IDLE in interative mode everything works just fine but when i run it by double clicking on it or from the command prompt it produces an error and doesnt start the program. i know the problem is with this line:

```
path_da=self.simdia.askstring("Path to start","Paths must be relative!")
```

i have imported all from tkinter.
path_da is suposed to be the string from the askstring dialog.
i set simdia to simpledialog as a public variable in my class.
I just don't understand why this works when running it using F5 in IDLE but not from the command prompt

Comment: define what you mean by "not working". What error does it produce?

Comment: `import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog` Is probably what you need, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8353233/404469).  (Also, now it seems like it could be duplicate question.)

Comment: self.simbia=simpledialog    global name simpledialog is not defined

Comment: that fixed it thats alot

Answer (score 1):

I flagged this as a dupe since the error received for using `simpledialog.askstring` without importing `simpledialog` from the `tkinter` module, is the same error you would get if just `simpledialog` was being used. If it's not considered a duplicate, here is the answer:

Quoting [Roger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353233/404469) to a similar question:

> IDLE uses Tkinter as its graphical environment. It is possible that
>   your code is relying on a side effect of an import by IDLE itself.
>   This is especially true if you use IDLE without a subprocess.
>
> The simpledialog module does not import when using

```
from tkinter import*
```

Try adding this to your code:

```
import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog
```